# How to disable form move

Tags: vb.net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# stop a form being moved.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907830/c-stop-a-form-being-moved)

how to disable the users ability to move form ?

Can't I disable the mouse click and drag on title bar so that the form can't be moved ?

Edit 1:

This is the code I tried, but the form flickers alot when I try to move it

```
Private Sub frmPayRoll_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    Me.Location = New Point(frmSimple.Location.X + 4, frmSimple.Location.Y + 108)
End Sub
```