# Is it possible to make a C# form non movable

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable form move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854107/how-to-disable-form-move)

I have a form that opens in the bottom right of the screen. I want to make this form unmovable - just able to close. I know how to remove the buttons for min/max etc but not how to make the form non movable.