# c# how can I make a windows form non movable and movable again

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form that I want to make it non movable when the user clicks a button and make it movable again when the user clicks again the button.

I found this solution here: [How do you prevent a windows from being moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907830/how-do-you-prevent-a-windows-form-being-moved)

But its an override so I think that is for making the form non movable for ever.

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: Just stick a flag in the overridden code that skips the code when set one way, or runs it when set the other way (the linked code simply ignores SC_MOVE messages, you can still override and optionally maintain the original functionality if you keep the call to base.WndProc())

Comment: use the solution you find, and just add in another condition (your button clicked)

Comment: i think that solution should work for you

Comment: IMO don't prevent user from moving a form. End user will feel app got hung!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a flag:

```
private bool _preventMove = false;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0×0112;
    const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

    if(_preventMove) 
    {
        switch(message.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
               int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
               if (command == SC_MOVE)
                  return;
               break;
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Set the flag to true/false to disable/enable movement

Comment: I will place that in my BaseForm class, so MainForm is BaseForm do I have to do MainForm.Invalidate() in order to execute it?

Comment: No idea - not tried to hook WndProc before but I assume that messages are pumped pretty continuously from the queue so I'd imagine that on it's own will be enough