# Sql transaction rollback from other form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, sqltransaction

I have 2 Forms:
[image]
1.MainForm :

in which users are asked to input name, Family, then there is button named as "payment detail"(which opens Form2).

2.Form2

The user input the payment detail and click on Save button. Then this transaction insert the new row in sql table and this form will be closed (Step 2). While MainFrom is still Open I would like, on user click on Save button on MainForm (Step 3), transaction of Form2 committed, but If user close the Main form then Form2 transaction roll backed.

I would appreciate your suggestions for this scenario ?

go throw steps 1,2,3

Comment: Francesco, your question is really not clear when it comes to what you would like to achieve. I tried editing it but is still very unclear. Try to make your question understandable.

Comment: You mean if your 2nd form is open and the user closes the 1st form, it should be rollbacked? I would request you to open your 2nd form in modal form, so that user cannot access 1st form when 2nd form is active.

Comment: no,I mean if 2nd form saved then form1 saved transaction in form2 commited.
If 2nd form saved then form1 canceled transaction in form2 roll backed.

Comment: Isn't enough to make form 1 not possible to close until form 2 is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
class MainForm()
{
    private TransactionScope _scope;
    public void SaveButton_Click()
    {
        _scope.Complete();
        Close();
    }
    public MainForm()
    {
        _scope = new TransactionScope();
    }
    ~MainForm()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, I strongly advise you **NOT** to do this. Since you will possibly have to wait a long time for the user to complete the inputs, you will run into all kinds of problems with transaction lifetime and locked database records.

Depending on your needs, consider picking one of the following solutions instead:

- If the user clicks cancel in MainForm, simply delete the created Transaction again.
- Pass the inputted values from the Transaction Form to the Main Form and only save the Transaction if the user clicks the Main Form's Save button.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your final goal is to save in a DB *name* and *surname* and then eventually also *payment details*  such as *date and amount*. For your own reasons you wont to display these input fields in two different forms. So, Form 1 could stay as it is. When Form 2 is open you need to prevent the user to close Form1 until save or cancel on Form 2 is clicked.
There are various possible approach to such scenario, the simple one could be to remove the close button from Form 1 when and until Form 2 is open. To achieve such, you can implement something like this:

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
   get
  {
   CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
   myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON ;
   return myCp;
  }
}
```

reference for the above is [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20379/Disabling-Close-Button-on-Forms)

Another alternative could be to  make your Form1 and Form 2 not movable on the screen and overlapping each other so that the user cannot access the closing button of Form 1 so he is forced to close Form 2 to get access to Form 1. Reference for such feature can be found here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907830/how-do-you-prevent-a-windows-form-being-moved). There other ways to do the above but this is what I had in mind now. Let us know.