# Prevent process window from being moved

Tags: winforms, winforms-interop

I've found a function which can be used for moving window and also hiding it when set width & height to 0.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx

I wonder if there are any ways with winform to prevent this function from being executed on another process (i.e: notepad.exe) or not.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this [how-do-you-prevent-a-windows-form-being-moved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907830/how-do-you-prevent-a-windows-form-being-moved)?

Comment: I've looked at that before sending this question :) . 
The solution is only for a form we code, but this question is about using a winform application to prevent another winform application from moving a process's window.