# Winforms - Disable that when user drags form by the border to move it, it resizes the form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, resize

I have a Winforms project with a form in it that is maximized (`this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized`).
When the user drags the form by its border to move the form around, it resizes to the size that I have set (which is not the maximum screen size since I do not know exactly to which values to set the `MinimumSize` property for it to be maximized on every screen).

I do not want this behaviour. I just want the form to stay maximized. I have set the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedDialog`, so that the user can not resize the form by dragging the borders. I have tried to re-set the maximized window state in all kinds of events, but they do not seem to work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's unclear what is your goal. Can you elaborate more? Do you want to prevent the user from moving the form? Do you want to prevent resizing? Do you want to set minimum size to size of desktop?

Comment: The goal that I am trying to achieve it to stop the form from becoming not-maximized. How that is achieved -by stopping the user from moving the form, by setting a minimum size- I do not care.

Comment: [How do you prevent a windows from being moved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907830/how-do-you-prevent-a-windows-from-being-moved)

Comment: A maximized form can't be resized or dragged around with the mouse, so it's unclear how this became a problem for you.  Post the code that duplicates the problem for us.

Comment: @LarsTech That's the weird part, because that is exactly what happened. I still don't know what caused it because I changed my implementation, but I'm glad I'm done with it ;p.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
this.MinimumSize = this.MaximumSize;
this.SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide;
```

and you can also try to write `onResize` event of the form

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Change the FormBorderStyle to one of the Fixed values: FixedSingle, Fixed3D, FixedDialog or FixedToolBar

```
// Define the border style of the form to a dialog box.
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

// Set the MaximizeBox to false to remove the maximize box.
this.MaximizeBox = false;

// Set the MinimizeBox to false to remove the minimize box.
this.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Comment: The FormBorderStyle is already set to FixedDialog and I have added the 'this.MinimumSize = this.MaximumSize' - line. Unfortunately, that does not help.

Comment: That does not help me since this is a question about the moving of the form causing it to resize, not about a user being able to resize it by dragging the sides of the form.

Comment: `FormBorderStyle` does not contain a definition for `FixedToolBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

in combination with

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
```

When you set this, you can't drag or resize the form.

However you will need to make your own close button or use "Alt+F4" to close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size, maximumsize and minimumsize to the same value.